# Refresh the data and paginator state

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I am using PrimeNG Turbotable `<p-table #dt`.

According [this](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table) `dt.reset()` will reset sort, filter and paginator state.
I am trying to find a way to reset paginator state and reload table data. (without the sort state reset)

This should happen on `(click)` of that button [image]

```
<p-button icon="fa fa-refresh" (click)="refresh()"></p-button>
```

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 6):

In .html file -

```
<p-table #dt [columns]="cols" [value]="result" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" [(first)]="first">
```

**Don't forget the brackets in [(first)]**

In .ts file, 
Add first attribute :

```
first = 0
```

wherever you want to reset, call below mentioned refresh function

```
refresh() {
    this.first = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your HTML looks like

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="cars" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" [first]="first">
```

where *first* is the index of the first row to be displayed, to reset only pagination, you should put its value to 0 :

```
refresh() {
    this.first = 0;
}
```

Then if you want to also reload your data, you just have to call your service again (if needed) in your *refresh* method.

Comment: when i set `this.first` to 0, nothing happened , when i set it to 1, then only the paginator (in the UI) is changing to page 1, but the content of table is not refreshed with the data of page 1.

Comment: in Html page i call the refresh() function: `<p-button icon="fa fa-refresh" (click)="refresh()"></p-button>`, in ts file: `refresh() {  this.first = 0;  }` when i click the button- nothing is happening

Comment: Please share all your TS and HTML code for that component or create a StackBlitz.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
refresh() {
    dt.first = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your template get a reference to your p-table by using @ViewChild

```
<p-table #turboTable [columns]="cols" [value]="cars" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" >
<p-button icon="fa fa-refresh" (click)="refresh()"></p-button>
```

In component file

```
    @ViewChild('turboTable', { static: false }) turboTable: any;

    refresh(){    
       this.turboTable._first = 0;
      //call your get service without filter
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i found solution, it's quite messy but it does the job. Use the @ViewChild to access your html dom: 
`@ViewChild('dt', { static: false }) dt: any;`

I saw there's a property called: sortOrder. It has two values 1 and -1. I forced to reload the sort by adding:

`this.dt.sortOrder = - this.dt.sortOrder;
this.dt.sortOrder = - this.dt.sortOrder;`